# Where can I find an Artifactory 6.10.0 in Windows Zip Installer?

Tags: artifactory

I have to upgrade Artifactory from 5.8.2 to 6.1.0 or any 6.x. to then Upgrade to 7.x, but I couldn't found the Windows zip to my virtual machine (I was looking in the JFrog page but just couldn't find it).

A 6.10.x Artifactory Windows installer.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below link to download the versions
https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/artifactory-pro/org/artifactory/pro/jfrog-artifactory-pro/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33482307)

Comment: @RumitPatel The question is literally asking for a link, can't help those cases.

Comment: Is there a oss version? I need to update a stone old version of the oss version of artifactory and I can only find the downloads to pro. I've checked everywhere on https://releases.jfrog.io/ui/repos/tree/General/

Comment: I'm also interested in OSS. Do you know where I can find it?. I Found them! See my answer

Answer (score 0):

For any one looking for the OSS packages, I have found this link [OSS ZIP](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/)

The problem is that the oldest version is **6.17.4**, and I was needing an odler one. So I guess I should upgrade to a new version first

###### UPDATE

Digging deeper, I found this other link with all version and every format:

https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/